# datatables format values with text align

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery data tables and fill the data via ajax as json:
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

```
var tbl = $('.mytbl').DataTable({
   "ajax": {
      url: "ajax/getData.php",
      type: "POST"
   }
});
```

The response of getData.php will be like this:

```
$myArray['data'][] = array(
   "Value 1",
   "Value 2",
   "Value 3"
} 
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

This works fine:
But how can I define that - for example - value 2 should be text-align right in my table?

Comment: can you share your html codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   var tbl = $('.mytbl').DataTable({
       "ajax": {
          url: "ajax/getData.php",
          type: "POST"
       },
       'columnDefs': [{
            "targets": 1,
            "className": "text-right",
       }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use render method available in `Datatables`.

```js
{
    data: 'value 2 column',
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        return `<span style="text-align:right">${data}</span>`;
    }
}
```

You can also use css if all column values are right aligned.